# "_ompi_mpi_int" in Funktion "_main" LNK2019

Tags: linker, linker-errors, openmpi

I was trying to compile [mpi_prime.c](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/samples/C/mpi_prime.c) with openmpi on windows. I tried it with the 32bit and 64bit version of OpenMPI_v1.6.2. I got these outputs.

> ```
> Microsoft (R) C/C++-Optimierungscompiler Version 17.00.61030 für x86
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
>
> mpi_prime.c
> Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.61030.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
>
> /out:mpi_prime.exe
> /LIBPATH:C:\Entwicklung\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-x64/lib
> libmpi_cxx.lib
> libmpi.lib
> libopen-pal.lib
> libopen-rte.lib
> advapi32.lib
> Ws2_32.lib
> shlwapi.lib
> mpicxx mpi_prime.c
> Microsoft (R) C/C++-Optimierungscompiler Version 17.00.61030 für x86
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
>
> mpi_prime.c
> Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.61030.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> /out:mpi_prime.exe
> /LIBPATH:C:\Entwicklung\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-x64/lib
> libmpi_cxx.lib
> libmpi.lib
> libopen-pal.lib
> libopen-rte.lib
> advapi32.lib
> Ws2_32.lib
> shlwapi.lib
> mpi_prime.obj
> mpi_prime.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_MPI_Comm_rank" in Funktion "_main".
> mpi_prime.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_MPI_Comm_size" in Funktion "_main".
> mpi_prime.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_MPI_Finalize" in Funktion "_main".
> mpi_prime.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_MPI_Init" in Funktion "_main".
> mpi_prime.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_MPI_Reduce" in Funktion "_main".
> mpi_prime.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_MPI_Wtime" in Funktion "_main".
> mpi_prime.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_ompi_mpi_comm_world" in Funktion "_main".
> mpi_prime.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_ompi_mpi_op_max" in Funktion "_main".
> mpi_prime.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_ompi_mpi_op_sum" in Funktion "_main".
> mpi_prime.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_ompi_mpi_int" in Funktion "_main".
> mpi_prime.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 nicht aufgelöste Externe
>
> Microsoft (R) C/C++-Optimierungscompiler Version 17.00.61030 für x86
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
>
> mpi_prime.c
> Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.61030.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> /out:mpi_prime.exe
> /LIBPATH:C:\Entwicklung\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-win32/lib
> libmpi.lib
> libopen-pal.lib
> libopen-rte.lib
> advapi32.lib
> Ws2_32.lib
> shlwapi.lib
> mpi_prime.obj
> mpi_prime.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_ompi_mpi_comm_world" in Funktion "_main".
> mpi_prime.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_ompi_mpi_op_max" in Funktion "_main".
> mpi_prime.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_ompi_mpi_op_sum" in Funktion "_main".
> mpi_prime.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_ompi_mpi_int" in Funktion "_main".
> mpi_prime.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 nicht aufgelöste Externe
> ```

**EDIT :** Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol means of course "unresolved reference to external symbol"

So I guess it had something to do with a 32bit vs. 64bit library problem using the wrong .dll as the 32bit version seems to produce less conflicts.

My plan looks like:

1. get it running on 32bit -> here I'm right now
2. get it running on 64bit
3. get it running with another compiler, eg gcc
4. get it running with my IDE codeblocks

Comment: Try adding `OMPI_IMPORTS` to the preprocessor definitions (found in _Configuration Properties_ -> _C/C++_ -> _Preprocessor_ -> _Preprocessor Definitions_)

Comment: I'll write a longer answer with proper refrences later. Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary Open MPI distribution for Windows ships with the library built as set of DLLs. The provided `.lib` files are simply import libraries for those DLLs. When calling functions from DLLs, their prototypes have to carry the `__declspec(dllimport)` extended storage-class attribute in order to allow the compiler to generate a slightly different code to call such functions or to access exported variables. Also functions with the `dllimport` storage-class attribute have their names prefixed with `_imp_`. Without `dllimport`, e.g. for `MPI_Init`, the compiler generates reference to the `_MPI_Init` symbol while the library actually exports `_imp_MPI_Init`, hence resulting in an unresolved symbol error.

Since Open MPI could be compiled either as a set of static libraries or as a set of DLLs, it uses a simple preprocessor mechanism to handle both cases with a single set of header files (e.g. `mpi.h`). If the preprocessor symbol `OMPI_IMPORTS` is defined, all MPI function prototypes get the `dllimport` treatment and do not get it otherwise. The same is true for the function prototypes from the ORTE and OPAL frameworks, with the corresponding preprocessor symbols being `ORTE_IMPORTS` and `OPAL_IMPORTS`.

To get your code to compile with the binary Open MPI distribution, you should add `OMPI_IMPORTS` to the list of preprocessor definitions, which could be found in the project's settings: *Configuration Properties* -> *C/C++* -> *Preprocessor* -> *Preprocessor Definitions*.