# MPI ORTED.EXE and NVINIT.DLL

Tags: dll, dependencies, mpi, dependency-walker

After solving my previous [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145806/ompi-mpi-int-in-funktion-main-lnk2019)  linking a MPI program, I tried to start that program unfortunatelly without much success.

> mpirun -np 4 mpi_prime.exe

Starting the program this way resulted in poping up 4 (for each process) overlapping windows stating:

> Die Anwendung konnte nicht gestartet werden (0xc00007b).

So I looked at the executeable with dependency-walker(DW), checking for wrong dependencies of .DLL files. As it turned out DW did find only 32bit (x86) .DLL files.

I startet a profile by running my executeable with DW (F7) again.

The log came up with a notable massage:

> ```
> GetProcAddress(0x00FF0000 [ORTED.EXE], "NvOptimusEnablement") called 
> from "NVINIT.DLL" at address 0x75266BDE and returned NULL. 
> Error: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden (127).
> ```

I don't have a clue whats this supposed to tell me, or how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself.

According to [Nvidia](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf):

> Starting with the Release 302 drivers, appl
>   ication developers can direct the Optimus
>   driver at runtime to use the High Performanc
>   e Graphics to render any application–even
>   those applications for which there is no existi
>   ng application profile. They can do this by
>   exporting a global variable named
>   NvOptimusEnablement
>   .

So applications can explicitly switch on my GPU Cores and use them.

I still don't know, what the connection between OpenMPI and my Nvidia Graphics card is, however I was able solving the problem by reinstalling a new Nvidia Graphics Card driver.