# Setting up Code::Blocks to compile MPI programs with MPICC.exe

Tags: compiler-errors, mpi, codeblocks, cl.exe

I succeded, [with some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145806/ompi-mpi-int-in-funktion-main-lnk2019), at compiling and running a MPI program from commandline on windows. Now I'm trying to compile this program with my IDE code::blocks and it fails.

`Under Settings -> Compiler... -> Other Settings -> Advanced Options -> Command line macros` I removed all the unnecessary flags and simly left:

`$compiler $file`

`Settings -> Compiler... -> Toolchain executables` I simly have the MPI wrapper `mpicc.exe` for C prgrams and `mpic++.exe` for C++.

When I now click on `Build` (Ctrl +F9) a small popup window opens stating:

`cl.exe - application error`

the error code is `0xc00000be`

in the build log window of code::blocks I get:

> ```
> mpicc.exe C:\Entwicklung\src\mpi_prime.c
> Skipping linking (no linker program set): C:\Entwicklung\src\mpi_prime.exe
> Process terminated with status -1073741634 (1 minutes, 37 seconds) 0 errors, 0 warnings (1 minutes, 37 seconds)
> ```

And here I'm stuck again, left with a few questions?

1. should I keep the mpicc.exe wrapper?
2. code::blocks tries always to invoke a linker etc. where can I turn that off?
3. I wanted to change my compiler from cl to gcc from the start, should I try that first?

**EDIT 1:**

> ```
> mpicc.exe /nologo /W3  /MD /Ox /DNDEBUG    /IC:\Entwicklung\CUDA\VS2012~1\VC\include /IC:\Entwicklung\CUDA\VS2012~1\VC\include  /c main.c /Foobj\Release\main.obj
> link.exe /nologo /LIBPATH:C:\Entwicklung\CUDA\VS2012~1\VC\include /LIBPATH:C:\Entwicklung\CUDA\VS2012~1\VC\include  /out:bin\Release\mpi_test_projektarbeit.exe "..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\Kernel32.Lib" msvcrt.lib msvcprt.lib "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\Kernel32.Lib"  obj\Release\main.obj   
> Process terminated with status -1073741634 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
> 0 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
> ```

I believe I did set up everything as it should be, however I still get the popup with the error code. I will fiddle with it. If nothing works, I'll try reinstalling code::blocks maybe this will help.

**EDIT 2:**

First, it's still not running. 
Second, I believe I have a much better understanding now whats going on and whats wrong.

By trying out diffrent things, I tried using cl.exe directly without the mpicc.exe wrapper. I chose `Settings -> Compiler... -> Microsoft Visual C++ 2010`, codeblocks was offering me. Trying to build project I received exactly the same [error message](http://i45.tinypic.com/2i6mj5e.png) (had to discipline my noScript to show me the message) as with `mpicc.exe`. mpicc.exe invokes cl.exe in its `mpicc-wrapper-data.txt` manifesto.

So with some google magic, I found at the codeblocks forum [this](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?action=printpage;topic=17266.0) page, where someone else had exactly the same error message. Their suggestion was to add the additional environment PATHs, which made me think. Before I ran `mpicc` from command line I had to run `vcvarsall.bat` first because I got an error that `mspdb110.dll` was missing. So I took a closer look at `vcvarsall.bat` which was invoking another batch-file `vcvars32.bat`. That file temporarily added PATH variables. So I added

> C:\Entwicklung\CUDA\VS 2012\Common7\IDE\

permanently to my PATH, and `mpicc.exe` can be invoked without any missing DLL error message, but trying to compile, shows up with some linker error unable to find `advapi32.lib`. I will look into it deeper and as soon as it runs on commandline without the help of `vcvars32.bat` I'll try it from CB again. I hope this is causing all my problems.

There is still one other thing confusing me a little bit, nothing serious but when I uninstalled CB and installed it again, CB had may
`"new" mpi` compiler setup somewhere saved. I checked my installation folder: all files were deleted after uninstalling it, so I also deleted the CB folder under `USER\AppData\`. However installing CB anew, the compiler settings where still present at CB startup, asking me if I wanted to import them?!?

Comment: Are you working with OpenMPI 1.6.2 (i.e. the last native Windows build)?

Comment: yes, exactly OenMPI 1.6.2-win32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you as far as building a 32-bit "Hello world" console project 
in Code::Blocks (12.11, at least) using the OpenMPI windows C compiler wrapper `mpicc.exe`, with the MS Visual Studio 10 toolchain (or later) installed:

I presume:

- Code::Blocks has detected the MS VC++10 compiler and it is listed as an available compiler
  in **Settings** -> **Compiler** under the drop-down menu **Selected Compiler**
- You have configured a new compiler, let's say, **mpi**, for the MPI wrapper, and that is the
  one in which you have changed the advanced compiler settings and other things.
- You have OpenMPI installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-win32`

Then:

- For a native `win32` build you will need to link `kernel32.lib`, and for that you will need to an up-to-date Windows SDK, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891
- In the Code::Blocks IDE, Navigate **Settings** -> **Compiler**. Select **mpi** and delete that compiler. (We'll start again)
- From the drop-down menu select **Microsoft Visual Studio 2010**; click **Copy** and call the
  new compiler again **mpi**.
- In the tab-menu, tab to **Toolchain executables** and set:

  - **Compiler's installation directory** = `<empty>`
  - **C compiler** = "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-win32\bin\mpicc.exe"
  - **C++ compiler** = "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-win32\bin\mpicc.exe"
  - Leave the other settings in **Toolchain executables** as they are and OK.
- The compiler will need access to Standard C Library headers (at least) and will need
  space-free (DOS) search pathnames. So now tab to **Search Directories** -> **Compiler**,
  where you will see `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include`.
- Select this path; click **Edit** and replace it with the DOS version of same, `C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\include`.
- OK out of **Compiler settings**.

Next set up the project.

- Navigate **File** -> **New** -> **Project**. Click the **Console Application** icon
- Click through the wizard:

  - Set **language** = **C**
  - Choose a project name and location
  - Set **Compiler** = **mpi**
  - Finish

Code::Blocks will then pop up a warning saying **Can't find compiler executable in your configured
search paths for mpi** (and will do likewise whenever your visit the project's build options). This
is a false alarm.

- Locate `kernel32.lib` under your SDK installation and get its pathname, say: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86\kernel32.lib"`
- Navigate **Settings** -> **Project** -> **Build options** and select **Compiler** = **mpi**
- In the tab-menu, tab to **Linker settings**
- Click **Add** beneath the **Link libraries** list. Add the full, quoted pathname you have noted
  for `kernel32.lib` and OK out of **Build options**.
- Build the project. A successful build log should look like:

  ```
  -------------- Build: Debug in mpi_test (compiler: mpi)---------------

  "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-win32\bin\mpicc.exe" /nologo /W3  /MDd /Zi /D_DEBUG    /IC:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\include  /c main.c /Foobj\Debug\main.obj
  main.c
  link.exe /nologo /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib"  /out:bin\Debug\mpi_test.exe msvcrtd.lib msvcprtd.lib "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86\kernel32.lib"  obj\Debug\main.obj   /DEBUG 
  LINK : bin\Debug\mpi_test.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
  Output size is 17.50 KB
  Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
  0 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
  ```

From there you can move on to some real MPI project, for which of course you will need to configure additional search directories and linkage options.

**UPDATE 1:**

Some problems I see with your latest failing build log:

- The compiler is being invoked as `mpicc.exe`, but per my answer it should be invoked by its full pathname, e.g. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-win32\bin\mpicc.exe"`. Can you attach a screenshot of the toolchain executables tab?
- The compiler option `/IC:\Entwicklung\CUDA\VS2012~1\VC\include` appears twice. This suggests you have configured this option globally for the `mpi` compiler and
  also for the project. Just configure it for the project.
- The linker option `/LIBPATH:C:\Entwicklung\CUDA\VS2012~1\VC\include` also appears twice, probably for the same reason. But `/LIBPATH:` should point to a directory containing
  library binaries (`.lib`) and you are pointing it at the same place as your `CUDA` *header* files - `/IC:\Entwicklung\CUDA\VS2012~1\VC\include`
- The `kernel32.lib` is in the linkage twice, first with a relative path `"..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\Kernel32.Lib"`, which may be invalid, and later with the absolute path `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\Kernel32.Lib"`. Again this probably results from combining redundant or incorrect global compiler
  configuration with project configuration.

Would urge you to get the **mpi** compiler working for the default "Hello World" console app by the steps I've given then move up to an elementary MPI app and get it working,
confining the additional configuration that you will require to the *project* rather than the *compiler*

Comment: This is a great answer and I believe I made all your suggested changes, however its not working. I Edited my original post and will try out reinstalling codeblocks.